# <use> tags not aligning properly in <svg> tags

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, css-grid

I'm having trouble getting my `<svg>` and '' tags to align properly in the designated spaces.  I defined the areas using CSS Grid and when applying the `grid-area` property to a `<div>` it all shows up as expected.  I took some screenshots to show what I mean.

Here's what the icons currently look like on the screen. Notice the first icon aligns to the left of the container while the other two align to the middle. I added grey backgrounds to the `<a>` tags the svg is in just to make them visible.

[image: screen]

Here's the first icon and the areas that highlight in the inspector.  Both the  and  tags match up on this one.

[image: first icon]

Here's the second icon, for some reason the  tag shifts over to the right.

[image: second icon]

The third icon does the exact same thing.

[image: third icon]

I'm creating an SVG sprite which looks like this so far

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none;">

    <symbol viewbox="0 0 79 146" id="illustration_icon">...</symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 180 146" id="content_icon">.......</symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 84 146" id="get_started_icon">....</symbol>

</svg>
```

The HTML for the container currently looks like this.

```
<div class="linkArea">

    <a class="firstLink linkIcon" style="background-color: #333;">
        <svg class="iconArea">
            <use class="iconSvg" xlink:href="assets/symbol_sprite.svg#illustration_icon"></use>
        </svg>
        <p class="titleArea">Illustration Design</p>
    </a>

    <a class="scndLink linkIcon" style="background-color: #888;">
        <svg class="iconArea">
            <use class="iconSvg" xlink:href="assets/symbol_sprite.svg#content_icon"></use>
        </svg>
        <p class="titleArea">Content Design</p>
    </a>

    <a class="thirdLink linkIcon" style="background-color: #333;">
        <svg class="iconArea">
            <use class="iconSvg" xlink:href="assets/symbol_sprite.svg#get_started_icon"></use>
        </svg>
        <p class="titleArea">Getting Started Design</p>
    </a>

</div>
```

The Css looks like this

```
.linkArea{
    z-index: 112;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [first-col-start] 1fr [first-col-end scnd-col-start] 1fr [scnd-col-end third-col-start] 1fr [third-col-end];
    grid-template-rows: [link-content-row-start] 1fr [link-content-row-end];
}

.linkIcon{
    display: grid;
    fill: #414D51;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;
    grid-template-areas:  "icon"  "title";
 }

.firstLink{ grid-area: link-content-row-start/first-col-start/link-content-row-end/first-col-end; }

.scndLink{ grid-area: link-content-row-start/scnd-col-start/link-content-row-end/scnd-col-end; }

.thirdLink{ grid-area: link-content-row-start/third-col-start/link-content-row-end/third-col-end; }

.iconArea{
    grid-area: icon;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: [icon-row-start] 1fr [icon-row-end];
    grid-template-columns: [icon-col-start] 1fr [icon-col-end];
    /*grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;*/
}

.iconSvg{
    grid-area: icon-row-start/icon-col-start/icon-row-end/icon-col-end;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 500px){
    .linkArea{ grid-area: scnd-third-row 1/first-third-col 1/scnd-third-row 22/third-third-col 34; }
}

@media screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width: 700px){
    .linkArea{ grid-area: scnd-third-row 13/first-third-col 1/third-third-row 1/third-third-col 34; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 2200px){
    .linkArea{ grid-area: third-third-row 1/first-third-col 11/third-third-row 27/third-third-col 23; }
}
```

I tried wrapping the `<svg>` tags in `<div>` tags and applying the `.linkArea` class figuring maybe there was a problem with applying the Grid attributes to SVG elements.  When I replace the svg tags all together everything lines up and behaves as expected.  Does anybody know why this is happening?  Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2X49Hkr3W35AxIbDJF13?p=preview) if you want to get a better look at what's going on.

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Is that the icons go on top of the background image?

Comment: I just added a photo